# How to scan a S3 file by command line in a Java application?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-s3

I need to scan a s3 object (jpeg, pdf) in my java application by Eset virus scanner.

```
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject("bucket", "key);
```

So I get S3 object and here is the command line that I should use

```
@SBINDIR@/esets_scan [option(s)] FILES
```

How can I use this command line in a java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the scan using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("esets_scan", "s3FileName");
```

Of course, you have to save your object to a file first and add more code to process the output of the scanner.

Comment: should i save file temporary or may i use just the s3object?

Comment: yes, it seems your `esets_scan` is a standalone program that only works with files, so yes, you should save it in a secure location and delete it afterwards.